# Is Cross validation and GridSearchCV required every time we train a model?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, supervised-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search

I have a repetitive process that will build a model weekly based on the previous week's data. So while in development I tried `GridSearchCV` and cross-validation to find the best hyperparameters and validate my model. Is this flow required every time I build a model or the best hyperparameters from my development time can be used without check every other time

Comment: The question should be when to retrain the model based on the data drift. If we are sure to retrain, how can we be sure that the past parameters _e.g. max_depth_ will work with old+new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to see the dynamic of change in the incoming data. The need for retraining is a direct function of change in data distribution.

If new data, theoretically, does not change the distribution then there is no need, however in practice that is simply impossible. So how much change in the distribution of data (both input and output) is a threshold for a retraining? This is the question. And more importantly how can I see that change in practice?

The empirical error shows you that change. Monitoring the performance of your system on a test set, you can observe if there is a significant drop and you can set a threshold for automatic retraining whenever you see that drop in performance (for this you need a test set which is different than the validation set you used for parameter tuning).

As data is dynamically change, **you must have new incoming samples inside your test set every time!**

Long story short:

1. Set up a **data extraction** pipeline which selects a part of new incoming, labeled data and injects it to the test set.
2. Set up a **monitoring** pipeline that uses that test set to calculate evaluation metrics on a scheduled basis.
3. Set up a **retraining** pipeline that is triggered by a significant drop in performance due to (2)

Comment: Hmm this makes more sense. I think distributions in my data would not change that frequently, maybe quarterly they might move. Will test this with pipelines you suggested to ascertain if I need to weekly training at all, thanks

Comment: welcome mate. good luck